# Chrome dev tools rulers not working in responsive

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, rulers

When I open chrome dev tools and if I press on the responsive any ruler extension that I have is not working. Some colleagues of mein have the page ruler extension and it works just fine on responsive but for me I just see the round shape and the ruler is not working. Any ideea why ?

Comment: My colleagues just use page Ruler, same extension that I use and they have no ideea why it is not working for me on responsive mode.

Comment: Are you using same Chrome version?

Comment: Yes, last version of it

Comment: Did you find a solution?